# matplotlib does not show legend in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cluster-analysis

I am trying to work on a clustering problem for which I need to plot a scatter plot for my clusters.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.merge(dataframe,actual_cluster)
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], c=df['cluster'])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

> df['cluster'] is the actual cluster number. So I want that to be my color code.

[image]

It shows me a plot but it does not show me the legend. it does not give me error as well.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Generating some random data:

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

n_clusters = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randn(1000), 'y':np.random.randn(1000)})
_, df['cluster'] = kmeans2(df, n_clusters)
```

### Update

- Use `seaborn.relplot` with `kind='scatter'` or use `seaborn.scatterplot`

  - Specify `hue='cluster'`

```py
# figure level plot
sns.relplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='cluster', palette='tab10', kind='scatter')
```

[image]

```py
# axes level plot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='cluster', palette='tab10', ax=axes)
axes.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image]

### Original Answer

Plotting (`matplotlib v3.3.4`):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')
for i, cluster in df.groupby('cluster'):
    _ = ax.scatter(cluster['x'], cluster['y'], color=cmap(i/n_clusters), label=i, ec='k')
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

Result:

[image]

Explanation:

Not going too much into nitty gritty details of matplotlib internals, plotting one cluster at a time sort of solves the issue.
More specifically, `ax.scatter()` returns a `PathCollection` object which we are explicitly throwing away here but which *seems to* be passed internally to some sort of legend handler. Plotting all at once generates only one `PathCollection`/label pair, while plotting one cluster at a time generates `n_clusters` `PathCollection`/label pairs. You can see those objects by calling `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` which returns something like:

```
([<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f60c2ff2ac8>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f60c2ff9d68>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f60c2ff9390>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f60c2f802e8>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f60c2f809b0>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f60c2ff9908>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f60c2f85668>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f60c2f8cc88>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f60c2f8c748>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f60c2f92d30>],
 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'])
```

So actually `ax.legend()` is equivalent to `ax.legend(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels())`.

NOTES:

1. If using Python 2, make sure `i/n_clusters` is a `float`
2. Omitting `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and using `plt.<method>` instead
   of `ax.<method>` works fine, but I always prefer to explicitly
   specify the `Axes` object I am using rather then implicitly use the
   "current axes" (`plt.gca()`).

---

**OLD SIMPLE SOLUTION**

In case you are ok with a colorbar (instead of discrete value labels), you can use Pandas built-in Matplotlib functionality:

```
df.plot.scatter('x', 'y', c='cluster', cmap='jet')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a question that bothers me for so long. Now, I want to provide another simple solution. We do not have to write any loops!!!

```py
def vis(ax, df, label, title="visualization"):
    points = ax.scatter(df[:, 0], df[:, 1], c=label, label=label, alpha=0.7)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.legend(*points.legend_elements(), title="Classes")
```

Comment: Easy and perfect solution.